# Formatted output for summary statistics in rmarkdown with results='asis'

Tags: r, r-markdown

I tried to get the summary statistics of a number of variables in my data
using a loop in Rmarkdown.

(I am using a loop as I am plotting the histograms etc as well, and `results='asis'` option so that I can implement raw Rmarkdown for section titles inside the loop.)

The problem is that when I print the summary statistics, the column numbers and the starts appear on the same line as in the below example. I prefer to have the respective values under the corresponding column name.

## Example

````
---
title: "test"
author: "me"
date: "3 June 2019"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
for (i in 1 :  3) { 
  cat('\n') 
  print(summary(iris[i*50 : 50, "Sepal.Length"] ))
}
```
````

### Output

> Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. 5 5 5 5 5 5
>
> Min. 1st Qu. Median
>   Mean 3rd Qu. Max. 5.7 5.7 5.7 5.7 5.7 5.7
>
> Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd
>   Qu. Max. 5.9 5.9 5.9 5.9 5.9 5.9

### Desired output

> ```
> Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.  
> 5    5      5      5     5      5 
> Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. 
> 5.7   5.7    5.7   5.7    5.7    5.7 
> Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. 
> 5.9   5.9    5.9   5.9    5.9    5.9
> ```

I have tried with `xtable` and `knitr::kable`, but I couldn't get the desired output. `xtable` require *tables of > 2 dimensions*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `xtable` was complaining about not having enough rows, I have transposed the output from the `summary` function. It worked.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "me"
date: "3 June 2019"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
for (i in 1 :  3) { 
  cat('\n') 
  cat(paste0("#The Title ", i, " \n"))

  print(xtable(t(summary(iris[i*50 : 50, "Sepal.Length"] ))))
}
````

[image]```

Answer (score 1):

The `knitr` chunk option `results="asis"` presumes that the output will be output "as is", intending that *"you can write out raw Markdown text from R code (like `cat('**Markdown** is cool.\n')`)"* (from https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html).

Perhaps change it to

````
---
title: "test"
author: "me"
date: "3 June 2019"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, comment=""}
for (i in 1 :  3) { 
  cat('\n') 
  print(summary(iris[i*50 : 50, "Sepal.Length"] ))
}
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason I wanted the `asis` option is that I want to write some *raw Markdown text from R*.  Maybe I should have clarified that in the question.